# download a file to TFS agent and read data from it using C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, tfs

I have a scenario to download excel sheet from a web page while executing a selenium test case. I need to read data from it for processing. The default file saving location is "Downloads". am able to do it on my local machine but this has to be done through CI pipeline. The file has to be downloaded to TFS agent and need to read file from there. Please let me know if any one has done this scenario.

Comment: if you can download  this to your local machine, then I would ask, where is the TFS Agent reside in your network? why not have the network team setup a shared drive that give your application `read/write` access.

Comment: We are using Azure cloud setup to deploy our code. So we will not be having a shared facility as such.

Comment: can a virtual folder / directory be setup on the cloud ? perhaps you can ask or put in a Microsoft Support Azure ticket

Comment: @Ch NR Have you resolved the issue by Giulio's answer below? any update?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a file is a Powershell one-liner:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $SourceUrl -OutFile $LocalFileName -UseBasicParsing
```

Call this code using the [Powershell Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/powershell) in VSTS and TFS 2015 or later.

A suggestion: Excel has a less known format called *XML Spreadsheet 2003* that is very easy to parse in Powershell, Python or any language with good XML handling.